# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c

Getting the following compiler error when building an app in Xcode 4.6.3

> **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**
>
> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was that I had used the same class wide variable in two different classes. Not sure why this is a problem, as they are not in my thinking global to the application, but just global to the class. The classes did not import to each other. Perhaps someone on here can provide a valid reason.

Here is some code to make it clearer.

ViewController1.m

```
@implementation ViewController1

int sliderSpeed = 500;
```

ViewController2.m

```
@implementation ViewController2

int sliderSpeed = 500;
```

Comment: The fault is yours and while your intentions are great, this is not worthy of a question for the record. The problem is quite simple, you declared a global variable twice. You should _always_ use the `static` keyword when you need to do this, in order to contain the scope of the variable to just the file it is defined in.

Comment: Thanks Mah for providing a reason. I'm not sure why this is not a worthy question. I had a problem, I spent time to trying to solve it, nothing in the error indicated an issue with using the same global variable. So information like this may help others in the future. I am relatively new to Objective C, and I program in 2 other languages at the same time...so my expertise can only stretch so far. So it is great to get a reason for the cause of a problem from more experienced people like your self!

Comment: Yes, I don't know why, but, if you just remove the value (int sliderSpeed;), it would work.